# ScrollToItemAtIndexPath doesn't work sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my collection, a `UICollectionView` instance, there are 25 cells. The first cell is at indexPath (0,0) and the last cell is at indexPath (0,24).

No matter I scroll from first cell to last cell or from last cell to fist cell, the destination cell is always nil, which seems that the `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` function did not scroll the cell to visible.

While when I scroll from second cell to fist cell, it goes well.

What can I do to scroll correctly between the first and the last?
I have tried `layoutIfNeeded`, but nothing different.

Here is part of my code:

```
    collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: false)
    print("indexPath")
    print(indexPath)
    guard let senderCell = collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell else{
        print(collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath))
        return
    }
```

And in consoler:

```
    indexPath
    <NSIndexPath: 0x79e53110> {length = 2, path = 0 - 24}
    nil
    indexPath
    <NSIndexPath: 0x7b8c2690> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
    nil
    indexPath
    <NSIndexPath: 0x79fc48e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
    indexPath
    <NSIndexPath: 0x79eb3950> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that there is a time interval between calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` and `collectionView` updating new visible cells.

So I have changed my code as following:

```
collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: false)
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {[unowned self] in
    guard let senderCell = collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell else{
        print("senderCell no found")
        return
    }
    //Do something with the senderCell
}
```

By adding a `delayTime` to wait for updating visible cells, we can get the cell we scrolled to.

Comment: this solution works great. Thanks man. however, i had to call scrollToItemAtIndexPath in the viewDidLayoutSubviews again so that the cell fits in the screen. For me without that the next cell was partially displayed.

Answer (score 0):

How your indexPath was created?

You can try to create it in the way like:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:25 inSection:0];
```

Should works…

Comment: My way is the same as yours. Thanks anyway.